# Writing txt file from Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis-3, export, text, virtual-layer

I have a Virtual Table which is a result set for a particular process.

```sql
select
  "RECORD_IDENTIFIER",
  CAST ("UPRN" AS textstring) AS UPRN,
  "KEY",
  "WARNING_CODE",
  "EXCEPTION"
from Exceptions
where sent = 0
```

The whole process should be run by co-workers who have no programming knowledge but just need to run the process. The result of the query needs to be output to a text file `.txt` without field names with every field comma-separated and enclosed in double-quotes.

I have no idea how to do this last part i.e. export the virtual query to a `.txt` file. Any ideas?

Comment: Right-click on the virtual layer, export as CSV, rename the `.csv` into `.txt` and delete first line ?

Comment: Thanks J. Yes I could do that but you can't save as txt or remove the field names and you have to positively set the string quoting - I want to avaid this by just having a process run that will handle all this otherwise you have to do it manually by opening the txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a short code (not strong enough for all errors but works in QGIS 3.*x*) for export to `export_dir` a `file_name` for the layer `layer_name` :

```py
import os
import csv

export_dir = "/home/me/my_dir/"
layer_name = "Exceptions"
file_name = "Exceptions.txt"

valid = True
os.chdir(export_dir)
try:
    lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
except IndexError:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
        f"The layer {layer_name} isn't loaded", Qgis.Critical, 5
    )
    valid = False

if valid:
    with open(file_name, mode="w") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(
            csv_file,
            delimiter=',',
            quotechar='"',
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
        )
        for feat in lyr.getFeatures():
            csv_writer.writerow(feat.attributes())

    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
        "Export done !", Qgis.Success, 5
    )
```